# How to perform Date operations in Doctrine without writing native queries in MySql or other DB backend?

Tags: php, mysql, date, doctrine, abstraction

I was going through the documentation of Doctrine.

I want to migrate my Code Igniter codebase's model portion to **Doctrine ORM**.

I have written many complex queries including date operations e.g. add two dates, add days to date etc using **DATE_ADD** etc.

Basic usage of Doctrine is it provides you **abstraction** as in if you change your DB backend from MySQL to MSSQL or other, your code base should be least effected.

Now I want to ask does Doctrine offer some function for date manipulations or we will have to write MySQL native queries?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In all cases I would recommend to use php for date operations. But if you want some sugar in DQL (doctrine query language) you can hook additional functions to it, there is a bunch of extensions [here](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql/DateAdd.php) follow the documentation on how to hook them [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language)
Of course doctrine will not let you use native queries with hydration, so if you want to have this power of your database use PDO. Also if you use doctrine2 there are [behavioral extensions](https://github.com/l3pp4rd/DoctrineExtensions)

Comment: Hmmm----------having a look at the code base---------from surface it seems we will have to write the corresponding DQL functions